# Folders in Apple Notes app

Tags: notes.app

How do you determine what folder a note resides in, in the Notes app? I have about 20 folders and put 30 or so notes in many folders.
All databases use to have some way to view a path.

Answer (score 1):

It does depends on what iOS device you are using but generally
The title above all the notes in that folder indicates the folder name, as shown in the picture.
If you are editing inside the note on an iPhone for instance, the back button is titled with the folder name.

[image: Example]